# How to install Sqelectron in Linux?

Tags: linux, ide, electron

I'm a new Linux user and I want to install a MySQL IDE. I use Sqlectron in Windows, so I want to install this IDE now in my Linux computer. I downloaded the .zip file but I don't know what to that after unzip it.

I'm using Elementary OS based on Ubuntu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latest version of sqlectron has a .deb file to install in debian like distro https://github.com/sqlectron/sqlectron-gui/releases/latest

Answer (score 0):

To install sql electron goto `https://github.com/sqlectron/sqlectron-gui/releases/tag/v1.35.0`

find packages depending on your distro either deb, or rpm

for deb

```
sudo dpkg -i path/to/package_file.deb
```

for rpm

```
rpm -ivh path/to/package.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can double click the downloaded sqlectron*** .deb package and do a GUI based installation in Linux.